# probability question with proof type question

Tags: probability

If $P (A \cap B) > P (A)P(B)$, then events A and B are positively correlated.

Show if $P(A\mid B) > P(A\mid B^c)$, then $A$ and $B$ are positively correlated.

I know $$P(A\mid B^c) = \frac{P(A \cap B^c)}{P(B^c)}$$
$$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

but I don't see how I can turn this into $P (A \cap B) > P (A)P(B)$

Comment: maybe this helps P(A)=1-P(A^c)

Answer (score 1):

Note that:$$P(A\cap B)>P(A)P(B)\iff P(A\mid B)>P(A)$$

And if: $$P\left(A\mid B\right)>P\left(A\mid B^{c}\right)$$ then: $$P\left(A\mid B\right)=P\left(A\mid B\right)P\left(B\right)+P\left(A\mid B\right)P\left(B^{c}\right)>$$$$P\left(A\mid B\right)P\left(B\right)+P\left(A\mid B^{c}\right)P\left(B^{c}\right)=P\left(A\right)$$

Comment: Out of curiosity...what is a negative probability? Or are you using "probability" to refer to any signed measure?

Comment: No, I want to avoid trivial cases where e.g. $P(B)=0$. Negative probabilities do not exist as far as I know. Maybe I am too cautious.

Comment: Ah, ok...thx...haven't heard of neg. prob. either.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A|B)>P(A|B^c)\implies \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}>\frac{P(A\cap B^c)}{P(B^c)} \implies (1-P(B))P(A\cap B) > P(B)P(A\cap B^c) \implies P(A\cap B)-P(B)P(A\cap B)>P(B)P(A\cap B^c)$

$\implies P(A\cap B)>P(B)[P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)]$

However, $P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c) = P(A)$ hence we get:

$P(A\cap B)>P(B)P(A)$

$\square$